# Designing a Reverb

Tags: reverb, design, mixing

Hi everybody. I´ve been using reverbs for a while and I´m curious about what´s the proccess you use to design the right space through a Reverb. Which parameters and which workflow do u choose to follow?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When I am listening the project (edited or pre-mixed), in my head I have an idea what should I add or reduce and how it generally supposed to sound. That include the amount and kind of reverb I add. There is no specific workflow or parameter that I follow. I trust my ears and my experience and knowledge help me achieve the idea I have.

Answer (score 3):

I find it best to set the early reflections and reverb decay time first. This gives you a sense of size. Actually, if like me you're using the stock reverb and are not sure which algorithm will yield the best result, start by comparing all the reverbs with the same early reflections and decay timings.

Then, give your environment the right color using frequency-domain and time-domain processing. The AIR reverbs in PT8 are a nice improvement to the good old D-Verb.

So I find it better for my reverbs to find a good timing and then give it the right color.